# What is the fastest way to map numpy array of unsigned integer {0,1} to float {1,-1}

Tags: python, numpy, casting

I have a numpy array of `np.uint64` holding only `0` or `1` values, and I have to map `0` to `np.float64(1.0)`, and `1` to `np.float64(-1.0)`.

Since the interpreter doesn't knows that it has only to convert `0` and `1`, it uses a costly general algorithm, so I thought to use an array with the result, and use the `uint64` as index for the array, avoiding any conversion, but it is even slower.

```
import numpy as np
import timeit


random_bit = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(10000), dtype=np.uint64)


def np_cast(random_bit):
    vectorized_result = 1.0 - 2.0 * np.float64(random_bit)
    return vectorized_result


def product(random_bit):
    mapped_result = 1.0 - 2.0 * random_bit
    return mapped_result


np_one_minus_one = np.array([1.0, -1.0]).astype(np.float64)


def _array(random_bit):
    mapped_result = np_one_minus_one[random_bit]
    return mapped_result


one = np.float64(1)
minus_two = np.float64(-2)


def astype(random_bit):
    mapped_result = one + minus_two * random_bit.astype(np.float64)
    return mapped_result


function_list = [np_cast, product, _array, astype]

print("start benchmark")
for function in function_list:
    _time = timeit.timeit(lambda: function(random_bit), number=100000)
    print(f"{function.__name__}: {_time:.3f} seconds")
```

I get these times:

```
np_cast: 178.604 seconds
product: 172.939 seconds
_array: 239.305 seconds
astype: 186.031 seconds
```

Comment: Isn't `randint` exclusive of the high value? I haven't tested it, but wouldn't you just get an array of 0s?

Comment: @jared. You are right. I corrected it.

Comment: so what times do you get?

Comment: `your `product` seems to be the most straightforward, and does wlll.  But in my testing `np.where(random_bit,-1.0,1.0)` does even better (the times are not drasticallly different).

Comment: Using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) is probably the fastest way. Is numba available in your environment? I am concerned because your times are 100 times slower than mine.

Comment: @ken When I tried to use numba with numpy, it got even slower.

Comment: I hope you realize that the time you are getting is the total time taken to run each of those simulations, 100000 times? What time are you ideally going for?

Comment: I tried to replace float multiplication to integer one in your `product` function
`mapped_result = 1.0 - 2 * random_bit` and got 1% to 6% acceleration. Though my times are ~200 smaller.

Comment: @tutizeri Could you share the code you tried?

Comment: `(1-2*x.astype(np.int8)).astype(float)` is the best variation I've found.  I.e. convert to small integer type for fast maths operations, then back to float at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this ~4x faster by using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org), for the general Nd case this could be:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.vectorize
def numba_if(random_bit):
    return -1.0 if random_bit else 1.0

@nb.vectorize
def numba_product(random_bit):
    return 1.0 - 2.0 * random_bit
```

Or in your specific 1d case you can use explicit loops to make it faster:

```
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def numba_if_loop(random_bit):
    assert random_bit.ndim == 1
    result = np.empty_like(random_bit, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(random_bit.size):
        result[i] = -1.0 if random_bit[i] else 1.0
    return result

@nb.njit
def numba_product_loop(random_bit):
    assert random_bit.ndim == 1
    result = np.empty_like(random_bit, dtype=np.float64)
    for i in range(random_bit.size):
        result[i] = 1.0 - 2.0 * random_bit[i]
    return result
```

Timings (`mason` is `lambda x:(1-2*x.astype(np.int8)).astype(float)` from the comments):

```
%timeit np_cast(random_bit)
%timeit product(random_bit)
%timeit _array(random_bit)
%timeit astype(random_bit)
%timeit mason(random_bit)

assert np.array_equal(np_cast(random_bit), numba_if(random_bit))
assert np.array_equal(np_cast(random_bit), numba_product(random_bit))
assert np.array_equal(np_cast(random_bit), numba_if_loop(random_bit))
assert np.array_equal(np_cast(random_bit), numba_product_loop(random_bit))

%timeit numba_if(random_bit)
%timeit numba_product(random_bit)
%timeit numba_if_loop(random_bit)
%timeit numba_product_loop(random_bit)
```

Output:

```
6.58 µs ± 218 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
7.58 µs ± 251 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
11 µs ± 9.34 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
7.32 µs ± 674 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
6.86 µs ± 153 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
1.89 µs ± 25.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
2.07 µs ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
1.6 µs ± 14.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
1.78 µs ± 5.31 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: strange deltas on your timings, on my x86 laptop my variant takes ~24µs, `np_cast` is ~32µs, while numba versions are all around 17µs.  i.e. keeping things as bytes is 70% of the time, while numba is only 50%.  I got a similar deltas with an ARM CPU.  numpy is 1.26.0, numba is 0.58.1

Comment: Numba it's 5X slower on my pc. Are you using some special numba wheel compiled for gpu or something else?

Comment: using numba 0.58.0 and numpy 1.25.2 from conda-forge, python 3.10.9 on an M1 pro

Comment: @tutizeri are you calling the numba function once before timing it? otherwise you're also timing the compilation

Comment: @nin17 I see. I added this line, and it worked faster:
'_ = numba_if_loop(np.array([0]))  # force compilation'

Comment: Besides, the random_bit array can be overwritten, to avoid creating a new array, except that it has a different type. Do you know a cheap way to change his type without creating a new one?

Comment: @tutizeri potentially by creating a view with a different type: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html